# Como deixar um item com traço no meio? Com <del>?

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para usar o `<del>` em um menu, que ao clicar nele ele ficar com o traço no meio ("tachado") e sem a função do mouse over. somente a setinha.

Comment: "ao clicar nele ele ficar..." Por favor explique melhor sua pergunta. Você quer que após o primeiro clique ele adquira esse efeito visual, e a partir de então ele fique desabilitado? Ou é outra coisa?

Answer (score 6):

### Se for apenas um menu com *mouseover*:

Você não precisa usar nem o `<del>` <sup>1</sup> nem o `<strike>` se for apenas para um efeito visual. Veja um exemplo com CSS:

CSS:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Neste exemplo, o link fica sem traço nenhum, mas quando você põe o mouse em cima, ele fica "cortado", graças ao `text-decoration`.

A propriedade `cursor: default` faz com que o cursor permaneça como a seta padrão, em vez da "mãozinha". <sup>2</sup>

> Veja funcionando no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/rxtkmncp/)**

<sub>1. como bem lembrado pelo @bfavaretto, o `del` só deve ser usado para ítens realmente deletados e/ou cancelados de uma lista</sub>

<sub>2. sugestao do @mgibsonbr</sub>

### Se for realmente uma lista em que você queira marcar e desmarcar ítens:

Para isto, precisamos improvisar usando `checkbox` para aceitar os clicks:

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label {
   text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div><input type="checkbox" id="C1" /><label for="C1">Checkbox um</label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="C2" /><label for="C2">Checkbox dois</label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="C3" /><label for="C3">Checkbox três</label></div>
```

Funciona desta maneira: primeiro, usamos `checkbox` para aceitar o efeito de "liga e desliga" ao se clicar nos ítens. Como a idéia é da identificação ser feita por um traço, escondemos os checkboxes com CSS, e aplicamos o efeito em seu respectivo `label`.

Isto funciona bem, pois o `label` serve como *proxy* para o controle principal, quando indicamos o parâmetro `for`.

> Veja funcionando no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/hd0eradc/)**

Comment: Perfeito isso mesmo,,,

Comment: Tipo para ele ficar selecionado, usa-se algum tipo de selectecd ? Digo assim: ao selecionar alguma opção, ela ficar selecionada.

Comment: @fabiano basta usar o checked do checkbox: `<input type="checkbox" id="C1" checked="checked">`

Comment: isso eu ví aqui, nnão tinha visto seu exemplo, sorry !!!

Comment: @fabiano, se solucionou marque como resolvido.